# how to get disk space with different category

Tags: cocoa

Such as the picture, it's infomation from Disk Utility of system.

[image]

i want to know how many spaces of Apps, Photos, Audio .....
Any one know how to get this info? Should i use `nsmetadataquery` to search and then calculate the total size?

```
NSPredicate *searchPredicate;
    searchPredicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"kMDItemContentTypeTree == 'public.image'"];
    [metadataSearch setPredicate:searchPredicate];
```

After Some hours research, i found the solution to implement this, so i will close this case now.

Comment: This shouldn't be the best way to find, But, you can recursively travel all the files and keep on add the file sizes based on the filetypes...

Comment: @AnoopVaidya , do you know what the types for each category, for example, Apps includes "kMDItemContentTypeTree == 'public.excutable" and others?  because the total size is not equal to 57.95GB

Comment: why don't you share your answer with us ?